# What's with the recent white background div.container?

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, google-chrome

I use Chrome with the Stylist extension, and up until a few days ago everything looked okay with my darker style for StackOverflow. However, now it seems there is a

```
<div class="container">...</div>
```

with a white background on it that seems to have a set height.  Why was this added recently?  It does not extend all the way down so I see the top part of the page as white background and the rest as my dark background, is this this intended outcome?

[image]

Notice the dark background below the white, I have no problem resolving this with Stylist, just wondering why this showed up.

Chrome 4.1.249.1036 beta (41514)
Stylist 2.0.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect it was part of the change to make the top-bar stretch across the whole screen. The gray bar at the top with the links used to just stretch from the mailbox icon to the end of the search box, but it was changed to span the whole page so it could include the StackExchange link.

That's done with a horizontally-repeating background image:

```
background:#FFFFFF url(img/bg-header.png) repeat-x scroll left top;
```

I think if the color portion `#FFFFFF` were changed to `transparent` it would fix the problem

Comment: Yes, modified my Stylist to use 'transparent' on the .container in the css just as you suggested and that worked like a charm.  Perhaps they will make that change in production some time.

Comment: good catch. it will be on production soon.

Comment: Verified the fix is in production this morning. Thanks!